# Cholesky factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cholesky-decomposition

Posting link here because it is as much math as it is programming:

[Replacing Cholesky factorization from IMSL MCHOL (Fortran) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827250/replacing-cholesky-factorization-from-imsl-mchol-fortran-in-c-sharp)

(Feel free to delete if inappropriate)

(Apologies for having lapsed into abject mathematical ignorance and incompetency over the last few decades).

Thank you for getting this far!

From the documentation of the function I'm trying to replicate:

*Computes an upper triangular factorization of a real symmetric matrix A plus a diagonal matrix D, where D is determined sequentially during the Cholesky factorization in order to make A + D nonnegative definite.*

*Routine MCHOL computes a Cholesky factorization, RTR, of A + D where A is symmetric and D is a diagonal matrix with sufficiently large diagonal elements such that A + D is nonnegative definite. The routine is similar to one described by Gill, Murray, and Wright (1981, pages 108−111). Here, though, we allow A + D to be singular.*

*The algorithm proceeds sequentially by rows. If A + D is singular, the Cholesky factor R is taken to have some rows that are entirely zero. The i-th row of A + D is declared to be linearly dependent on the first i − 1 rows if the following two conditions are satisfied: (images that I can't really put in here, see the documentation [here](http://www.roguewave.com/Portals/0/products/imsl-numerical-libraries/fortran-library/docs/6.0/stat/default.htm?turl=mchol.htm))*

I want to make sure I really understand what is being solved for here. Cholesky factorization wants a positive definite matrix, so we're solving for the smallest modifier that does that? And after that, it's merely a matter of algorithm?

Comment: In the question you linked you indicated that you "don't care" about the math; so, why would you post this to a site devoted exclusively to mathematics? Any explanation you might get will most certainly be mathematical in nature which, as you've made plain, you don't care about...

Comment: Actually, I do care, but A) I was hoping to get a quick answer for the proof of concept, which is obviously not happening, so B) I'll edit the question, because if I have to spend time, I might as well actually try to understand, but C) my LinAlg days are so far behind me that someone will have to explain this to me very, very slowly and I'm quite embarrassed about that. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Have you taken a look at AMD's ACML? It's free (though may come with some distribution restrictions) and has complete implementations of BLAS and LAPACK; to use in C# you'll just have to PINVOKE an unmanaged call to the DLL. And it will almost certainly be faster than any managed implementation you can find.

Comment: Yep, in fact Math.NET can be compiled to use it. I think it's the algorithm that's my problem. Will add to the post.

Comment: Right, more or less you want to have a modified Cholesky decomposition. Vanilla Cholesky requires that matrices given to it are symmetric positive definite; what modified Cholesky does is to perturb the diagonal elements of your matrix as needed such that Cholesky can proceed as usual. What the routine returns is the triangular matrix that when multiplied with its transpose yields the original matrix with perturbations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a partial answer: why is such a routine is needed?

A Cholesky factorization is $XX^t = A$.  But not all *A* have such a factorization.  Whenever matrices get you down, try the 1×1 matrices: numbers.  The transpose of [x] is just [x], and so we get:
$$[x][x]^t = [x^2] = [a]$$
only works (for real numbers *x*), if *a* ≥ 0.  You can't take the square root of a negative (and get a real number), and you can't take the square root of a "negative" (definite) matrix.  So what happens if we ask for the Cholesky decomposition of [−2]?  Well the routine says −2 is too small, so we'll just choose *d* = 2, and find the Cholesky factorization of [*a*] + [*d*] = [*a* + *d*] = [−2+2] = [0]. $$[0][0]^t = [0] = [-2] + [2]$$

Given any symmetric matrix, it can be thought of (after finding some other special decompositions) as a diagonal matrix: in other words as a few separate numbers.  For example take *a* = diag(1,−2,3).  We can almost find a nice Cholesky decomposition: $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{-2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{-2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} \end{bmatrix}^t = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$
except for the pesky $\sqrt{-2}$ not being a real number.  Never fear, *d* = diag(0,2,0) is here!
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} \end{bmatrix}^t = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Things are a little messier when *A* and *D* are not both diagonal (we can assume one is diagonal, but not both for this algorithm), but I think the basic idea is the same.  Fix negative diagonal entries, well, negative [eigenvalues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/eigenvalue).

Comment: As an additional note: the use of modified Cholesky I'm most familiar with is in the optimization of multivariable *nonlinear* functions and the solution of *nonlinear* equations. The reason for this apparent paradox is that algorithms for doing those things often involve the solution of a symmetric linear system (e.g. the Hessian matrix for optimization, or the cross-product of the Jacobian matrix for nonlinear equations), and due to roundoff error and a bunch of other factors, stuff that are theoretically, usually SPD may not be so. That's where the perturbation comes in...

Comment: I know this problem from factor-analysis, where the diagonal of the (symmetric) covariance-matrix partly represents uncorrelated variance, aka item-specific variance (including error in measurement). To solve the problem to find a best representation of the covariance by less-than-rank factors, first the itemspecific variance is removed from the diagonal. But this can only be estimated and might be too optimistic such that negative eigenvalues occur (Heywood-cases). Possibly such a routine as mchol is/was then used to find a spd-solution by *iteratively approximating* the optimal diagonal.